# How to copy paste HTML DOM elements in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to copy the `<span data-dcvarid=261>{GENDER-261-234}</span>` element and paste only like dom element. Now it's past like plain text. How can I fix that?

```
import { CopyToClipboard } from 'react-copy-to-clipboard';

const copiedValue = `<span data-dcvarid=261>{GENDER-261-234}</span>`;
... 

<CopyToClipboard text={copiedValue} onCopy={() => message.success(`${name} was copied`)}>
  Click to copy
</CopyToClipboard>
```

Comment: Please revise to provide some context. Why copy/paste? Why not clone the element? We need to understand the whole picture. It may not be appropriate to even use the clipboard.

Comment: I need to understand the right way of doing that ... if it's possible to do with  clone then please advise me how can I archive that ... btw I am trying to copy that span element and paste into texteditor and send to backend.

Comment: After paste user should see `{GENDER-261-234}` but actually behind that it should be `<span data-dcvarid=261>{GENDER-261-234}</span>`

Comment: You can do this by dynamic content ```dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: copiedValue }}```

Comment: @RomikMakavana can you please provide the whole code ?

Comment: @someone Actually, you had not detailed, how and where you paste the copied value.

Comment: @RomikMakavana, I am using `tiny editor` , and I want to past there.